# Windows Console Resizing ignored - Screen buffer messed up

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-console

I'm going to ask the same question as countless people before me. I've tried about every solution out there but I seam to get the same output every time. I'm creating a console game engine and want to improve fps by using the windows API. However, Now that I have rotating polygons and such implemented, I'm realizing that the console resizes itself when the requested size extends about 100 x 100 characters. When this happens, the console gets resized to about 50 x 25 and the screen buffer shows absolute gibberish when I scroll to the right.

Here are some pictures:
[image: see the miniature window?]

[image: see the gibberish?]

I will supply just the relevant code for now but if anyone needs anymore I'd be glad to add it.

```
m_width = width;
m_height = height;

m_hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
m_hConsoleIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

if (m_hConsole == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    log += "Invalid std output console handle\n";

COORD bottemRight = { (signed)width, (signed)height };

if (!SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(m_hConsole, bottemRight))
    log += "Error setting screen size\n";

m_screenBound = { 0, 0, (signed)width - 1, (signed)height - 1 };
if (!SetConsoleWindowInfo(m_hConsole, TRUE, &m_screenBound))
    log += "Error initializing window info\n";

if (!SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(m_hConsole))
    log += "Error setting active screen buffer\n";
```

I've also tried the HWND solution:

```
HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
RECT rect = { 0, 0, width, height };
MoveWindow(hwnd, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top);
```

I tried switching the window info setter and the screen buffer size setter and changed the window info rect to {0, 0, 1, 1} to no prevail. The output is pretty much exactly what you see in the pictures above.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolescreenbuffersize) of `SetConsoleScreenBufferSize function`: "The specified width and height cannot be less than the width and height of the console screen buffer's window. The specified dimensions also cannot be less than the minimum size allowed by the system. This minimum depends on the current font size for the console (selected by the user) and the `SM_CXMIN` and `SM_CYMIN` values returned by the `GetSystemMetrics` function."

Comment: If this function `SetConsoleScreenBufferSize` fail call [`GetLastError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms679360) to get the error code.

Comment: Does that mean I have to set the window size to { 0, 0, 1, 1 }, then set the console buffer and finally set the window to { 0, 0, width -1, height - 1 }?

Comment: What are return values of `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXMIN)` and `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYMIN)` for you?

Comment: it returns 136, 39. I don't know what these numbers mean but if they correlate with the font size maybe you're on to something here

Comment: These numbers mean the minimum size allowed by the system. Your 50 x 25 size is too small to be allowed. You need use larger size more than 136 x 39. For example, you can try 140 x 45 to see if it helps.

Comment: that doesn't change anything. It still resizes to about 50x100

Comment: @I can't reproduce this issue. You can refer to [official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/scrolling-a-screen-buffer-s-window) or provide a mini, complete and reproducible code sample so I can try to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

After noodling around with my code a bit, it turns out (based on the Microsoft documentation) that I need to something like this:

```
SMALL_RECT screen = { 0, 0, 1, 1 };
SetConsoleWindowInfo(m_handle, true, &screen);

COORD buffer_size = { width, height };
SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(m_handle, &buffer_size);

screen = { 0, 0, width - 1, height - 1 };
SetConsoleWindowInfo(m_handle, &screen);
```

This works for me now but thanks for your suggestions!